# Given $S^1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ that is the unit circle

Tags: general-topology

I must conclude if the following statements are true:

a) $[0,1) \thicksim$ $S^1$

b)$[0,1) \thicksim [0,2\pi)$
(In (b) I thought about considering the function $f(x)=2\pi x$, but I'm not sure)

Comment: What does $\sim$ indicate?  Homeomorphism?

Comment: Same cardinality, related to bijection, I still don't have the contents of homeomorphism

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect this.  $\sim$ can mean many different things.

Answer (score 1):

For part b. your function $f(x) = 2\pi x$ can work as a bijection.  Everything in $[0,2\pi)$ gets mapped to by something in $[0,1)$ (surjectivity), and $2\pi x = 2\pi y$ implies $x=y$ (injectivity).

For part a., try the function $x \to (\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$.